# How to generate an inline GetElementPtr instruction?

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I have some piece of code like this (`systemFun` is defined as `i32 @system(i8*)`):

```
auto cmdPtr = GetElementPtrInst::CreateInBounds(
        ArrayType::get(TYPE8, 1 + cmdCStr.size()),
        cmdStr, ArrayRef<Value*>(indexList, 2), "", returnBB);
builder.CreateCall(systemFun, {cmdPtr});
```

which generates the following LLVM IR:

```
%1 = getelementptr inbounds [10 x i8], [10 x i8]* @cmd, i32 0, i32 0
%2 = call i32 @system(i8* %1)
```

However, when I compile this C code using Clang:

```
system("echo haha");
```

The following LLVM IR is generated:

```
call i32 @system(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([10 x i8], [10 x i8]* @cmd, i32 0, i32 0))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I would like to generate the latter code, where the result of `getelementptr` is used directly in the function call, without being assigned to a temporary variable `%1`.

I tried omitting `NameStr` and `InsertAtEnd` (`returnBB` is a BasicBlock), but it generates code like

```
call i32 @system(i8* <badref>)
```

Please kindly tell me how to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "inline" version is a ConstantExpr, generated using [ConstantExpr::getGetElementPtr()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantExpr.html#a2622f4935d20e7aa385c90c85357cc43), the [other one is an instruction](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GetElementPtrInst.html).

The `ConstantExpr` class is the best format to use for global variables because it neccessarily takes no CPU time at runtime, but the instruction works for all kinds of pointers, even if not constant. (A pointer to a global variable is constant.)